# Error: identifier expected, but got: paramStr(1)

Tags: nim-lang

So, I had this code:

```
import std/os
import system/io
echo paramStr(1)
if declared(paramStr(1)) == true:
    echo It exists
else:
    echo It doesn't exists
```

And then while I was compiling this error ocurred:

`Error: identifier expected, but got: paramStr(1)`

I don't know what could be the cause of it, maybe it could be the type of `paramStr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `declared` wrongly. It's used to check if some identifier has been declared. E.g.

```
import os

when declared(paramStr):
  echo true
```

Echoes `true` because `paramStr` has been declared in `os`. Remove the `import os` line and it echoes `false` (without throwing an `import error`).

If you want to check if you have a `paramStr(1)`, you can do it with `if paramCount() > 0` instead.

Also, you don't need to import `system` nor `system/io`, as they are automatically included in your program.

If you find yourself coding a complex command line, take a look at the `parseopt` included in the batteries, or at the `docopt` wrapper in http://nimble.directory